onCall function can't be found
i'm trying assign custom claims using an onCall function but i get a CORS error.
This function is located in the functions folder in document adminClaim.js and referenced in index.js:
exports.adminClaims = require("./adminClaims");
//other functions

And the function itself
exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return admin
    .auth()
    .getUserByEmail(data.email)
    .then((user) => {
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        admin: true,
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return {
        message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin`,
      };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      return err;
    });
});


This is how i call the function on the client side when a user logs in:
const hostname = window.location.hostname;
  const functions = getFunctions(getApp());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hostname === "localhost") {
      const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
      connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
    }
  });

onSubmit((e) => {

 const addAdminRole = httpsCallable(functions, "adminClaims/addAdminRole");
    addAdminRole({ email: e.target.value }).then((result) => {
      console.log("Result: ", result);
    });
}

   

From the error, i see that the system can't locate the function i'm calling even though its listed in the available functions or i'm not referencing it properly.

Function us-central1-addAdminRole does not exist, valid functions are:
us-central1-adminEmails-profileCreationEmail-0,
us-central1-adminClaims-addAdminRole,
us-central1-fnTracking-trackPortfolioImages,...

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Shouldn't it be httpsCallable(functions, "adminClaims-addAdminRole")? (note dash instead of slash)

How did you reach the conclusion that the name of the function should be "adminClaims/addAdminRole"?  Cloud Functions doesn't have any sort of hierarchy or namespacing.  There is just the name that you use to export the function from index.js.  Also it looks like you're not importing the function properly.  Why don't you first try putting the entire function directly into index.js?

samthecodingman, the issue is around how i have exported the function. @DougStevenson, you're right, i've called it in the index file. I'll just have to learn how to export and call it properly once i make more callable functions.
